# Mahapps & Prism HamburgerMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mahapps.metro

i am currently building an WPF-App with Prism and Mahapps.

I ran into a Problem while implementing an HamburgerMenu with Prism.
Is there a way to fill the HamburgerMenu via the Region?

As an example, when i use an control derived from an ItemsControls with an region attached to it (via the attached property RegionManager.RegionName), it will automatically fill any registered view to this region into the ItemsControls.

Is there an way to mimic this behavior for the HamurgerMenu?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I managed it.

1) Name a region for the menu items collection.

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
            <controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MenuRegion"/>
</controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
```

2) Define a region adapter for the HamburgerMenuItemCollection

```
public class HamburgerMenuItemCollectionRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<HamburgerMenuItemCollection>

{
    public HamburgerMenuItemCollectionRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehaviorFactory)
        : base(regionBehaviorFactory)
    {
    }

    protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, HamburgerMenuItemCollection regionTarget)
    {
        region.Views.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (HamburgerMenuGlyphItem element in e.NewItems)
                {
                    regionTarget.Add(element);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new AllActiveRegion();
    }
}
```

3) Register the adapter in the bootstrapper.

```
protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
{
    RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
    mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(HamburgerMenuItemCollection), Container.Resolve<HamburgerMenuItemCollectionRegionAdapter>());
    return mappings;
}
```

4) Define menu item in Prism module

```
public partial class OptionOneMenuItem : HamburgerMenuGlyphItem
{
    public OptionOneMenuItem()
    {
        Glyph = "/Assets/OptionOne.png";
        Label = "Option One";
        Command = ApplicationCommands.NavigateCommand;
        CommandParameter = typeof(OptionOnePageView);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

5) Finally register menu items in module initialsation.

```
protected override void InitializeModule()
{
    RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MenuRegion", typeof(MyOptionOneMenuItem));
    RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MenuRegion", typeof(MyOptionTwoMenuItem));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the Answer,
I've already found a solution by myself (similar to your suggestion) :)

Comment: I tried this solution, but I'm getting an invalid cast exception.
Also, there's no way to call InitializeComponent from the inherited class constructor, as the method don't exist in the base class.

Comment: Can you post your code? I can't quite see why you would need to call InitializeComponent. Can you show this and the exception location?

Comment: I don't think I need to call InitializeComponent anyway, I'm just commenting because you put it into your sample. The exception was solved. It was an error while creating the command.